# Classpath showing path of old machine

Tags: java, classpath

I imported an old project to my computer and added all the necessary jar file but .classpath is showing path of old machine. How do i change it ? manually it will take big time to update
[.classpath image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhFhm.png)

Comment: did you do some research and search for similar questions on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of time spending finally found the solution 
here it is :- 
All I need to do was to select .classpath in storage format drop down (refer screenshot)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvvNm.png)